# Unable to install typo3 version 6.2.9 on apache webserver

Tags: apache, installation, webserver, typo3-6.2.x

I want to install typo3 CMS v6.2.9, but I don't know why the FIRST_INSTALL file would be ignored :(.

The directory tree of the webserver looks as follows:

```
html
   website
      typo3_src (symlink -> ../typo3_src-6.2.9)
      index.php (symlink -> typo3_src/index.php)
      typo3 (symlink -> typo3_src/typo3)
      .htaccess
      FIRST_INSTALL
   typo3_src-6.2.9
```

Does anyone know where the problem is?

Comment: UPDATE: the problem was a server configuration setting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was a security server configuration problem, changing SuPHP settings as follows works for me:

```
check_vhost_docroot=false
```